# Playwright browser is reopening every test statement

Tags: javascript, playwright

How to stop browser from reopening every time the the every test statement is done? I mean the code below is supposedly in 1 page continuing. Why is it the browser closes, open again and execute the second test. How to prevent that? Thanks

````
  test('When user logs in', async ({page}) => {
    const commonAction = new CommonAction();
    await commonAction.gotoPage(page);
    await expect(page).toHaveURL('https://uat.mercator.createit.dev/login');
    await commonAction.login( page, janEmail, janPasswd );
  });

  test('Then user is in my account page', async ({page}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyAccountPage(page);  
  });
  
  test('When user goes to newsletter subscriptions', async ({page}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.goToNewsSubscription(page);  
  });

  test('Then user is in Newsletter subscription page', async ({page}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyNewsletterPage(page);  
  });

  test('When user updates subscription', async ({page}) => {
    const newsletterAction = new NewsletterAction();
    newsletterAction.subscribe(page);
  });

  test('Then user is redirected to My Account page after subscription updates', async ({page}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyAccountPage();
  }); 
})```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the tests that share the same page and rely on the previous test results you need to wrap them in [test.describe.serial](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test/#test-describe-serial) and initialize the page in `beforeAll`, see [this guide](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-retries/#reuse-single-page-between-tests) for more information.

Your example would look like this:

```
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');

test.describe.serial('use the same page', () => {
  /** @type {import('@playwright/test').Page} */
  let page;

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  test.afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
  });

  test('When user logs in', async ({}) => {
    const commonAction = new CommonAction();
    await commonAction.gotoPage(page);
    await expect(page).toHaveURL('https://uat.mercator.createit.dev/login');
    await commonAction.login( page, janEmail, janPasswd );
  });

  test('Then user is in my account page', async ({}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyAccountPage(page);  
  });
  
  test('When user goes to newsletter subscriptions', async ({}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.goToNewsSubscription(page);  
  });

  test('Then user is in Newsletter subscription page', async ({}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyNewsletterPage(page);  
  });

  test('When user updates subscription', async ({}) => {
    const newsletterAction = new NewsletterAction();
    newsletterAction.subscribe(page);
  });

  test('Then user is redirected to My Account page after subscription updates', async ({}) => {
    const navigationAction = new NavigationAction();
    await navigationAction.verifyAccountPage();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate! I was late but it works!